# Actionbar background color changes on scale

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, scale

I used this code to change actionbar color that is used with appcompat lib:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.teleblue));
```

but in use color changes and in different screen sizes color is different.
I don't want to clean the original question with tricky ways. how can I fix it?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.color.teleblue` is a resource identifier not a `#AARRGGBB` color.

Depending on what type `actionBar` is some of following options may or may not be available:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundResource(R.color.teleblue); // if it's Toolbar

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( // if it's ActionBar
    new ColorDrawable(
        actionBar.getThemedContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.teleblue));

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( // if it's ActionBar
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        actionBar.getThemedContext(),
        R.color.teleblue));

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( // if it's Toolbar
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        actionBar.getContext(),
        R.color.teleblue));
```

Comment: when I use                                         actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(
    new ColorDrawable( actionBar.getThemedContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.teleblue));                                                                                     result is 2e5b81 but when use my own code result is 7a778 and default color is 212121. but why same color changes with different codes?

Comment: What do you call *result*?

Comment: result=color of actionbar

Comment: As i said `R.color.teleblue` is not a color but a resource identifier so you can use it to look up resources (`getDrawable(R.color.teleblue)` or `getColor(R.color.teleblue)` but *NOT* use it as a color int (`new ColorDrawable(R.color.teleblue)` or `setBckgroundColor(R.color.teleblue)`.

Comment: o yes. that's because resource identifier is a int and can be use as a argb or rgb color. thank you